# Can I modify msg.value from inside contract?

Tags: solidity

I know `msg.value` is read only but I wanna create a code when user call function I will random set extra value and this value should be add to total payment, mean value + gas.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
  function testFunction() public payable {
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(2200000000000000);
  }
}
```

This function not working of course, but is there any way to do this from inside the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

This is because the `msg.value` is coming from the user. The user has signed the amount they want to send along with the transaction and you cannot change that because it would be a huge security flaw.

Even the gas the contract can use is predetermined since its calculated and the user signs the amount they are willing to pay for fees.

Imaging a user signing to send 1 ETH and then you change that to 2 ETH. Where would that extra 1 ETH come from?